# Why data doesn't save?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to handle form and save data from form do my db.
I want to get some data from form and another data before saving(like current user_id, current datetime). I've created method in Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Post();
        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $model->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->getId();
            $model->created_at = \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate(new \DateTime(),'php:Y-m-d');
            $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            if($model->upload()) {
                $model->image = ('web/images/' . $model->image->baseName . '.' . $model->image->extension);
            } else {
                $model->image = 0;
            }
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['site/blog']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('blog/create', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

and my Post model:

```
class Post extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $title;
    public $text;
    public $image;
    public $comments;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'text'], 'required'],
            [['image'], 'file',  'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }
    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->image->saveAs(\Yii::getAlias('@app') .'\web\images\\' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension))
            return true;
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(),['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
}
```

but now when I send my form only user_id,created_at, saved in my db. What I did wrong?

Comment: This might because of `$model->image = 0` and this might be cause of `false` response from upload..

Comment: If `$model->save();` fails, you should render the view to see th errors in your form (`return $this->render('blog/create', ['model' => $model]);`)

Comment: You should enable error reporting and/or check your log files in order to track down the problem. Perhaps it is the double slash in the path that makes the file upload fail i.e `'\web\images\\'`? Also you might consider using forward slashes instead. You should also make sure so the `web\images` folder is writable by the webserver.

Comment: but either title and text weren't saved. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this:

```
public $title;
public $text;
public $image;
public $comments;
```

From your model. That's all. ActiveRecord is automatically mapping columns from your table.

Comment: Have a nice day! ;)